# AS3 Polymorphism: Changing classes from within that class

Tags: actionscript-3, polymorphism

This is a very simplified version of my issue but should be enough for me to solve my problem.

Let's assume I have classes DressingRoom, Person, Hat, Badge, and Foreman and the app allows you to give a person different types of hats while they're in the dressing room, and if it's a foreman, he can get a badge as well. 
What I'd like is for the user to become a Foreman if you give him a white hat and have him just be a regular person if it's not.

Is it possible to set a certain class to a subclass of itself within Person rather than have to do it in Dressing Room class (which would be easy to do).

```
public class DressingRoom{
  public var length:int;
  public var occupant:Person;
}

public class Person{
  public var name:String;
  public var hat:Hat;

  public function hatChanged():void{
    if (hat.color==0xFFFFFF){
      this =  new Foreman(name,hat);
    }
  }
}

public class Hat{
  public var size:int;
  public var color:uint;
}

public class Foreman() extends Person{
  public var badge:Badge;

  public function hatChanged():void{
    if (hat.color!=0xFFFFFF){
      this =  new Person(name,hat);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is NO.   You're on the right track with your dressing room concept though where you hold occupant:Person in a wrapper class, and check to see if it's of type Foreman when needed.

Comment: Ya, it's just very inconvenient with the way I've done it to do it from the dressing room and it would be nice to do it from within the class itself. Thanks for the response though - I know I need to stop wasting time with that now at least.

Answer (score 1):

seems like a good candidate for the decorator design pattern. there's quite a bit on that and as at [as3dp.com](http://www.as3dp.com/?s=decorator)

Answer (score 1):

Strange question :) You can use composition instead of inheritance. It could looks like this:

```
public interface IHat{
  function get status():HatStatus
}

public class ForemanHat implements IHat{
  private const status:ForemanStatus = new ForemanStatus();
  public function get status():HatStatus {return status;}
}

public class Person{
  private var status:HatStatus;

  public function setHat(hat:IHat):void{
    status = hat.status;
  }

  public function get status():HatStatus{ return status}
}
```

You can add more hats simply.